# androidx.appcompat.appcompat.R does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

After upgrading/refactoring into AndroidX i am getting this error 
`androidx.appcompat.appcompat.R does not exist`
in the code it is showing **appcompat** symbol cannot resolve

Comment: please check if you have `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Comment: Add your gradle files(App and build both) here. @Eldhopj

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message as you. I've tried everything without it being much help to me.

I finally solved it after lots of trial and error.

In my case, the error was this :

-previous
...`searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.appcompat.R.id.close_btn)`

Here, I just deleted the duplicated `appcompat` and made it like this :
...`searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.close_btn)`

and it works. maybe it was a mistake created during the androidX migration.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

goto **Gradle** at the right side of android studio
then select your project ,click on app, click on build , double click on assemble
it will open the build output window here you can find the file that is causing the error.You have to resolve this error to generate the `R.class` file.

If everything is fine but still `R.class` is not generating, try to **Gradle** synk your project or invalidate cache and restart your android studio. Hopefully it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra appcompact from here.

from - 
androidx.appcompat.appcompat.R

to - 
androidx.appcompat.R

Answer (score 0):

check your .xml file may there is an error, Or if there is no error then clean your project and rebuild. After this, if it will not resolve then clear cache and restart android studio. There is also an option just migrate your project to androidX.